# Create Pulldown Items in E4

Tags: eclipse-plugin, e4

In E3 you could do something like that:

```
  <menuContribution allPopups="false" locationURI="toolbar:org.acme.toolbar">
     <command commandId="org.acme.dummy"
              id="org.acme.dropdown"
              style="pulldown" />
  </menuContribution>
  <menuContribution allPopups="false" locationURI="menu:org.acme.dropdown">
     <!-- commands and stuff -->
  </menuContribution>
```

In my brand new *Application.e4xmi* I'm missing the option to create pulldown (or dropdown) items. There are only the types "check", "push" and "radio", and as far as I can tell there is no specialized tool item for the use case.

How do I create pulldown items in my E4 *Application.e4xmi*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 'Menu' check box on the Handled Tool Item and Direct Tool Item items. Checking this will add a 'Menu' as a child of the item where you can add the drop down items.